# Can't compare values in if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to ios. I want to check if statement is true, but this condition gives true everytime even when it's false.

```
 NSMutableArray *passengers=loginObj.passengers;
 PassengerObj *passenger=[passengers objectAtIndex:0];
    if([[passenger checkedIn] objectAtIndex:0])
    {
       [somestatement];
    }
```

in debugger

```
_checkedIn  __NSCFArray *   @"1 object" 0x168b8200
   >[0] __NSCFBoolean * @"0"    0x37e696d4
```

Comment: I believe `@"0"` evaluates to `true` because it isn't `nil`.

Comment: ye but how to do it properly?

Comment: Will the objects always be `@"0"` or `@"1"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your array only contains *strings* that contain a 1 or a 0, you can compare the string:

```
if ([[[passenger checkedIn] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"0"])
```

Of course it would be more readable to have an array of `NSNumber`s and use

```
if ([[[passenger checkedIn] objectAtIndex:0] boolValue])
```

Comment: It would be even more readable to Right clic the content of the If statement, and extract as a method that returns a bool, and call it `IsPassenderCheckedIn`, for example. That's something I like to do with my  "complicated" or long if statements ; after that it just reads like prose.